# jpa: LIKE on a Lob field

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with a String field marked as Lob:

```
@Lob
public String getJson() {
    return json;
}
```

I need to do a query with a like condition on this field, using jpql. I cannot use native query because the code must be compliant both with Oracle and Postgresql. I'm using hibernate as jpa implementation.
The query doesn't return anything, even if it is translated correctly (I did a query on the v$_sqlarea of oracle to see it and its parameters). Executing the translated query on squirrel works perfectly.

Am I trying to do a wrong/not permitted operation on a lob field?
Does anyone do the same thing with success?

Comment: Do the logs show any caught error?  Are you using the latest JDBC drivers for both databases in case its a driver support issue?

Comment: No error. It simply returns no records. I'm using hibernate 4.0.0 and weblogic 12.1.3, jpa 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Support for using the `LIKE` predicate operator on `@Lob` annotated fields is likely going to be hit or miss depending on the dialect you're using.  That is because it depends on the data type that is used for mapping the `CLOB` data to the database column.

For example, a SQL Server dialect might map a `@Lob` annotated `String` field to the `TEXT` data type, while deprecated, does allow the `LIKE` operator.  But another dialect might map that field to a data type that the database does not allow the `LIKE` operator on.

Other dialects might allow `LIKE`-like operations against `CLOB` columns; however they do so through special database-specific functions.  In those cases, you'd have to use those functions to support your searches, if that requirement is applicable to your dialect.

Comment: I'm using Oracle dialect or Postgresql dialect. Both database supports like on Clob fields.